# Pathos pool prints mysterious error

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I'm running

```
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool
pool = ProcessingPool(4)
pool.map(...)
```

and the following gets printed in run time:

```
not in depth 2
not in depth 3
not in depth 1
not in depth 2
not in depth 3
not in depth 1
not in depth 2
not in depth 3
not in depth 1
```

What does this mean? Does it imply any steps I can do to prevent errors increase performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message is coming from `statsmodels`, when regression results are being pickled (see [issue raised on github](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/4118#issuecomment-343562418)).

`ProcessingPool` pickles the input when sending to the workers, so that's why this particular message appeared when mapping my function, but not when running it iteratively.